# How to filter the data bound to GridView control by the QueryString?

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq-to-entities, asp.net-controls

I am a new ASP.NET Web Forms developer and I am struggling now in with the best way of filtering the data by the value of QueryString before
binding it to the GridView control. I am binding the GridView to the GetData() method, and I would like to filter the data in the code-behind based 
on the value of the QueryString if there is a QueryString. **So should I do the checking of the QueryString in the BindGrid() method or in the 
Page_Load() method? And how should I do it?**

For your information, the GridView has a pagination capability as shown in the code-behind below.

Here's the C# code for the GetData():

```
public IEnumerable<Item> getData(Item itemObj)
    {
        List<Item> itemList = new List<Item>();
        using (ATMSEntities context = new ATMSEntities())
        {
            itemList = (from item in context.Item
                       select new Item()
                       {
                           ItemId = item.ItemId,
                           Name = item.Name,

                       }).ToList();
            if (itemObj.ItemId != 0)
            {
                itemList = itemList.Where(item => item.ItemId == itemObj.ItemId).ToList();
            }

        }
    }
        return itemList;
}
```

And here's the code-behind for the aspx page that has the GridView control:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(Request.QueryString["ItemId"] != null) //the filtration is not working here.
    {
        bindGrid();
    }
}

    private void bindGrid()
    {
        Item itemObj = new Item();
        var result = itemObj.getData(itemObj).ToList();
        gvItems.DataSource = itemObj.getData(itemObj);
        gvItems.DataBind();
    }


    protected void gvItems_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
    {
        gvItems.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
        bindGrid();
    }
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: In your model, can you have multiple items with the same ItemId?

Comment: @PraveenPaulose, No, it can't be. Each item has a unique id. However, this page could be accessible with no querystring, so in this case all the items will be displayed. And sometimes it might be accessible with a querystring, so it the data in gridview should be filtered by this ItemId.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the QueryString value to filter the list items. What you should be doing is this

```
private void bindGrid()
{
    Item itemObj = new Item();
    if(Request.QueryString["ItemId"] != null) 
    {
        itemObj.ItemId = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ItemId"]);
    }
    var result = itemObj.getData(itemObj).ToList();
    gvItems.DataSource = itemObj.getData(itemObj);
    gvItems.DataBind();
}
```

Comment: what about if I have multiple items with the same id? is it going to be different? if yes, could you please add this case to your solution as well. I really appreciate your help in this regard and thank you very much.

Comment: The solution will not differ if you have multiple items with the same id. The same logic would work. I hope this answers your query.

Comment: I would appreciate if you could show me the answer of this case as well.

Comment: I did not understand. I was saying that the same code would work even if you have multiple items with the same id.